# How can I convert a byte array to a bitmap and stream the images through a web server?

Tags: java

The project I am working on is capturing a frame from a security camera, with the help of [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) UNO and [Video Experimenter shield](http://nootropicdesign.com/ve/). Then I am sending the frame as byte arrays through a serial port. I would like to ask, how could I, with Java, convert back this byte arrays to an image, and stream this image - or even make this images a video and then stream it - through a web server?

The code I have stacked with is this:

```
//Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and save the image.

public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {

    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Got it!");
            int available = input.available();
            byte[] chunk = new byte[available];
            input.read(chunk, 0, available);
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(chunk);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
            ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", new File ("/home/zuss/images/image.BMP"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        } 
     }
}
```

That returns to my terminal window: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!`
continuously as long as arduino is sending data to the serial port.

Comment: _Video Experimenter Shield_ what is this?

Comment: In theory this should be possible yes, as long as you know what encoding was used. As long as you get all of the raw bytes out, you can decode it in the Java layer. You'll want to start with the [Java Media APIs](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/), good luck!

Comment: Well, I think it should be easy, because the buffer that contains the frame in byte arrays is equal to 1536 bytes, in 128x96 resolution. The frame is monochrome because of the size of the buffer!

Comment: I agree, the Java Media API should be able to get this up and running in no time.

Comment: [Video Experimenter shield](http://nootropicdesign.com/ve/)

Comment: Serial port is relatively slow so image streaming may simply prove to be impossible except for very tiny images.  Try calculate what you need and what you have.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - Yes, I can see that. It is a slow connection with low capacity micro-controller. Now, I am trying to understand how to just put the byte chunks received, into a byte array, and when that byte array complete at 1536 bytes, then construct and save the monochrome bmp image.

Comment: Why not just attach an IP camera? streaming live video is built in I believe. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Look at the edited initial post, in return I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null! error.

Comment: I have no idea how you would implement it in Java (and I'm sure you knew anyway), but an image is just an array of bytes representing the colour values for each pixel, so your image data (minus encoding) is being sent in the correct format already. "image == null" is making me think that the byte[] has either not finished sending or hasn't sent yet. Hope that helps

Comment: This needs a stacktrace.

Comment: Perhaps you are not getting all the bytes at once? When you do
input.read(chunk, 0, available);
you might not be getting all the image just yet. You might need to read from the stream in a loop until all bytes are received. And only then convert it to the image

Comment: You have the byte array. Stream that. You don't need to convert it to an image to send it. You need to convert it to an image to *display* it. And you are misusing `available()` in a way that is specifically warned against in its Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look something like this:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(chunk);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File ("/home/zuss/images/image.BMP"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int read = in.read(buffer);
while(read >= 0 ) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    read = in.read(buffer);
}
```